# Executing ffmpeg command using Popen

Tags: python, ffmpeg, popen, python-3.4

I have a strange problem trying to execute `ffmpeg` command using Popen.
I have the following piece of code, which I use for executing an external commands in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from datetime import datetime


class Executor(object):

    @classmethod
    def execute(cls, command):
        """
        Executing a given command and
        writing into a log file in cases where errors arise.
        """
        p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        output, err = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode:
            with open("failed_commands.log", 'a') as log:
                now = datetime.now()
                log.write('{}/{}/{} , {}:{}:{}\n\n'.format(now.day, now.month,
                                                           now.year, now.hour,
                                                           now.minute,
                                                           now.second))

                log.write("COMMAND:\n{}\n\n".format(" ".join(command)))
                log.write("OUTPUT:\n{}\n\n".format(output.decode("utf-8")))
                log.write("ERRORS:\n{}\n".format(err.decode("utf-8")))
                log.write('-'*40)
                log.write('\n')

            return ''

        if not output:
            output += ' '

        return output
```

I've tested it with others commands, but when I try to execute `ffmpeg` command - it fails.
I'm trying to convert some audio format to mp3 format.
Here is an example of my command:

```
ffmpeg -i "/path/old_song.m4a" "/path/new_song.mp3"
```

...simple as that.When I run it in terminal it works fine, but when I try to execute it using the above function it fails.
Here is the exact error:

```
----------------------------------------
21/9/2014 , 19:48:50

COMMAND:
ffmpeg -i "/path/old_song.m4a" "/path/new_song.mp3"

OUTPUT:


ERRORS:
ffmpeg version 2.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  9 2014 08:01:43 with gcc 4.9.0 (GCC) 20140521 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-dxva2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-pic --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
"/path/old_song.m4a": No such file or directory
Conversion failed!

----------------------------------------
```

...and as you can think of - the file exists.

I think there is something in passing the command to `Popen.communicate` but I don't know exactly.

Kind regards,

Teodor D.
PS: I'm passing the command to `Executor.execute as Python` list.

PSS: Calling the `Executor.execute` :

```
def process_conversion(self):
    for song in self.files_to_convert:
        current_format = song.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]

        old_file = '"{}{}{}"'.format(self.target_dir, os.sep, song)
        new_file = '"{}{}{}"'.format(self.target_dir, os.sep,
                                     song.replace(current_format, 'mp3'))

        command = ["ffmpeg", "-i", old_file, new_file]
        Executor.execute(command)
```

Comment: You've left out a critical piece of information: the exact call to `Executor.execute` that produces that output.

Comment: This output is from failed_commands.log file.In other words the output is after "ERRORS:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the double quotes in the name of the file. Use this instead:

```
    old_file = '{}{}{}'.format(self.target_dir, os.sep, song)
```

Comment: I can swear that I have tried that and it didn't worked.But guess I've changed something else after that.Just to make things clearer for me - double quotes are nessecery only in terminal use to tells the interpreted that the following thing is a single argument (if it contains whitespaces) ?

Comment: Correct; the shell uses whitespace to separate arguments within a string; quotes protect enclosed spaces. Python doesn't have to parse a single string as a list of arguments; you just use a `list` object.